# Take out video length from IDR or non-IDR (H.264/AVC – Bitstream Organization)

Tags: h.264, bytestream

I have a stream for a flash player that comes from H.264 Chunks - SPS, PPS, IDR and non-IDR. So far the FLV stucture is generated from the bytearray. The only problem left for me is to understand how I can get those **Timestamp UI24** that FLVTag need. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the time for each FLVTag you do:

1. First get the frame rate from SPS file, you need to check for  **timing_info_present_flag** to be 1;

> timing_info_present_flag : 1
>
> num_units_in_tick : 1000
>
> time_scale :120000
>
> fixed_frame_rate_flag : 1

So you count it like:

```
time_scale / (2 * num_units_in_tick) = frame_rate fps;
120000 /
```

2 * 1000 = 60 fps

After that you get the miliseconds per frame -> 1 / 60 = 0.01666(6)
So you count the frames (IDR and NDR) and you increase the timestamp accordingly. For SPS and PPS frame I drop the current timestamp to where we are currently.